# How to split source by buildType AND flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have an app with different package name for the buildTypes debug/release as well as for two productFlavors.

The interesting part of my build.gradle looks like this:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "com.example.app.flavor1"
        }

        flavor2 {
            packageName "com.example.app.flavor2"
        }
}
```

So there are for package names:

com.example.app.flavor1
com.example.app.flavor1.debug
com.example.app.flavor2
com.example.app.flavor2.debug

Everything is fine with the code. But because the modified package name get's messed up while merging the manifest I need to set some things like GCM permissions and content providers authority by hand for each valid package.

But how do it do it?
No matter if I put the `AndroidManifest.xml` into `src/falvor{1,2}` or in `src/{debug,release}`, I end up with only two configurations.
I tried things like `flavor1Debug` without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no official way to set resource files of the 'flavorBuildType' (like flavor1Debug) combination, so you have to do a little hack here.

First define the new path of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
project.ext.flavor1 = [
    debugManifest: 'src/flavor1Debug/AndroidManifest.xml',
    releaseManifest: 'src/flavor1Release/AndroidManifest.xml'
]

project.ext.flavor2 = [
    debugManifest: 'src/flavor2Debug/AndroidManifest.xml',
    releaseManifest: 'src/flavor2Release/AndroidManifest.xml'
]
```

Second, tell gradle to use the new AndroidManifest.xml in processManifest task. Now the problem is: sourceSet.manifest.srcFile is read-only, we can't just replace it on-fly. Since we're using separate resource (debug & release) for each flavor, we can copy the new AndroidManifest.xml to the origin flavor folder and gradle will build the APK file with right settings.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.processManifest.doFirst {
        if (project.ext.has(variant.productFlavors.name)) {
            if (project.ext[variant.productFlavors.name].debugManifest != null &&
                project.ext[variant.productFlavors.name].releaseManifest != null) {
                def manifestDirectory = android.sourceSets[variant.productFlavors.name].manifest.srcFile.parentFile
                if (variant.buildType.name.equals("debug")) {
                    copy {
                        from project.ext[variant.productFlavors.name].debugManifest
                        into manifestDirectory
                    }
                } else if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
                    copy {
                        from project.ext[variant.productFlavors.name].releaseManifest
                        into manifestDirectory
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    variant.processManifest.doLast {
        if (project.ext.has(variant.productFlavors.name)) {
            project.delete android.sourceSets[variant.productFlavors.name].manifest.srcFile
        }
    }
}
```

And for the AndroidManifest.xml, just leave the GCM related setting there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.example.free.debug"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.android.example.free.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.example.free.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

</manifest>
```

You can get sample code here : https://github.com/shakalaca/learning_gradle_android/tree/master/07_tricks

It supports both Google Maps API v2 & GCM cases, but I think it is easy to support content providers as well after minor code change.

Comment: Looks like its only working when building debug and release separately. Or does it work with building all things at once with `gradle assemble` too?

Comment: yes, as the main stuff lies in android.applicationVariants.all it'll process all things at once with gradle assemble :)

Comment: The processManifest has moved:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302965/could-not-find-property-processmanifest-on-com-android-build-gradle-internal-a