# Android Gradle - Add packageNameSuffix on specific productFlavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle Android Project with this product Groups and Flavors configuration:

```
/*
 * Define different flavor groups
 */
flavorGroups 'market', 'version'

/*
 * Defile product flavors
 */
productFlavors {

    amazon {
        flavorGroup 'market'
    }

    google {
        flavorGroup 'market'
    }

    flav1 {
        flavorGroup 'version'
        packageName 'com.company.flav1'
    }

    flav2 {
        flavorGroup 'version'
        packageName 'com.company.flav2'
    }

    flav3 {
        flavorGroup 'version'
        packageName 'com.company.flav3'
    }
}

// .. Other stuff
```

It works great. All sources and resources are merged correctly.
But for specific reasons I need the package suffix to be `.amz` for the `amazon` product flavor. How can I achieve that?

I tried this way:

```
amazon {
    flavorGroup 'market'
    packageNameSuffix '.amz'
}
```

but `gradle` throws an exception.

Comment: I once had a similar question, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18606152/2331953

Comment: I read this before @fix. By the way helped me a lot, when I started with this project. But the problem is that I'm not adding any suffix, I need to add one. Preferably somewhere in the debug and release tasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.
packageNameSuffix is strictly a property of Build Type.

I'd like to offer a way to customize the ProductFlavor's values for a given variant (ie a given combination of all flavor dimensions and of build type) but it's not possible at the moment.

Instead of a new dimension of flavor, you could do a "amzRelease" buildtype that extends the existing release buildtype and add a suffix.

If your current "amazon" flavor does more (configure versionCode/Name/etc...), it won't work though. You could then use both your amazon flavor and a amzRelease build type. It'll create a lot more variants than you need but it'd work until we have some better.

Comment: Thanks Xavier for your feedback. We decided to stick with same package name. This was required for our API to understand which users are accessing it, so I added a secret param as an workaround. Will be waiting for the plugin update. Your doing a great job, thanks.

Comment: i wanted to add - this is also required for our scenario. if there is any progress on this, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variant of the solution I've written about here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26585241/4177090

In short, you can find the combined variants using variantFilter and then update the appliciationId from there:

```
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    def flavorString = ""
    def flavors = variant.getFlavors()
    for (int i = 0; i < flavors.size(); i++) {
        flavorString += flavors[i].name;
    }
    if(flavorString.contains("amazon")) {
        variant.getDefaultConfig().applicationId variant.getDefaultConfig().applicationId + ".amz"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working atm because `applicationId` is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for gradle 1.0.0+:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavorName = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
    def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();

    if (flavorName.toLowerCase().contains("amazon")) {
        mergedFlavour.setApplicationId(mergedFlavour.getApplicationId() + ".amz")
    }
}
```