# Could not find property 'processManifest' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am currently trying to update Android Studio to 1.0.0-RC. This seems to require gradle Android plugin 1.0.0-rc1. After the update, I started having the following error:

```
`Could not find property 'processManifest' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@b9da89c.`
```

With some digging, it seems that `processManifest` is one of the deprecated properties that were removed in [0.14.3 version](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). Any idea what the new property name is? The same user guide has not been updated for the new version, so I can't find any documentation for it.

EDIT: Here is the code that needs the property. I use it to inject some build-time values into the manifest:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.processManifest << {
            def manifestOutFile = variant.processManifest.manifestOutputFile
            def newFileContents = manifestOutFile.getText('UTF-8')
                    .replace("{GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}", variant.buildType.ext.google_maps_key)
            manifestOutFile.write(newFileContents, 'UTF-8')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation for APK splits (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits) this method has moved into `VariantOutput` (available via `variant.outputs`):

**Deprecation Warning**: the current variant API contains some methods that have moved under its outputs. The method are still there, but will fail if there are 2+ outputs. They will be completely removed in 1.0
These are:

- get/setOutputFile
- getProcessResources
- getProcessManifest
- getPackageApplication/Library
- getZipAlign

Additional methods on `VariantOutput`

- String getAbiFilter()
- String getDensityFilter()
- Task getAssemble()
- String getName()
- String getBaseName()
- String getDirName
- set/getVersionOverride // optional versionCode override
- int getVersionCode() // returns either the versionCode override from the output or the versionCode from the variant itself

Comment: processManifest is both a task and a method. `getProcessManifest` would allow retrieving the file, but not retrieve the task. Thanks for the answer though, it's a start!

Comment: Yeah, it's not a full answer to your question. Feel free to edit this if you get farther along with it or post your own answer.

Answer (score 51):

I got this error as well after updating to Android Studio 1.0.0 on the Beta Channel.  However, I could not find any reference in my own gradle files to `processManifest`.  After some searching, I realized that I needed a new Robolectric gradle plugin:

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/releases

Using version 0.14.0 of the Robolectric Gradle Plugin (and version 2.4 of Robolectric) has resolved the error for me.

Comment: I don't think this applies to my case, because I don't use this plugin. But I did see a similar issue on a similar project: [gradle-android-test-plugin](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/27)

Comment: What a savior you are, as robolectric was my problem as well.

Comment: This was my problem as well. For Android Studio 1.0 build from December 5th, had to use Robolectric 0.14.1 plugin (0.14.0 was giving the error that it's not compatible with the gradle version)

Comment: Is life not cruel sometimes?

Comment: I commented out Robolectric in my gradle file altogether, and was still getting this error.  So I doubt Robolectric is to blame.

Comment: I experience the same problem. However, I was using the JCandK Solutions (robolectric) plugin (https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test) An upgrade to the newest version of the plugin fixed it.

Comment: in my case, change the .gradle file   classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.+' to   classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.+'  or if even later updated version will solve this problem

Answer (score 10):

I have not been able to find a solution to the problem, but simply a workaround. Android Gradle plugin Version 0.11 introduces a new API called [Manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger). It allows to achieve the same thing that my hack allowed me to do.

Here are the changes needed:

- Surround any variable that you inject in your manifest with `"${GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}"`
- Define a `manifestPlaceholders` map in each BuildType. That is:

  ```
  buildTypes {
      debug {
          manifestPlaceholders = [GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
      }
      release {
          manifestPlaceholders = [GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
      }
   }
  ```

That's it! The plugin will automatically replace those variables in your Manifest. Pretty neat!

Comment: Do you know any way to use the manifestPlaceholders for a specific buildType AND flavor? It would be extremely useful.. Looping trough variants doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Yep, check the link in the answer. They have something like this: 
`android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"defaultName"]
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
        }
        pro {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"proName" ]
        }
    }`

Comment: Yeah but that is only a placeholder per flavor, I need to define the placeholder for a specific flavor and only for a certain buildType. I seem to be able to do both separately but not the 2 conditions like (if (flavor=="myFlavor" && buildType = "release") that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 6):

```
android.applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    output.processManifest.doLast{ 
    def manifestFile = output.processManifest.manifestOutputFile
    def updatedContent =manifestFile.getText('UTF-8').replaceAll("UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE", "${variant.productFlavors[0].name}")
    manifestFile.write(updatedContent, 'UTF-8')
    }
}
```

}

I changed it in this way, which just add a new layer outside the older one. This works because `processManifest` is now in the `outputs` field.
Think this could be helpful.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer defies the point of the question. `processManifest` does not exist in the Android gradle plugin anymore (as of 1.0.0 rc). This solution does not work

Comment: hi verybadalloc I am using gradle version 1.0.0 and it works, processManifest does not exist in the variant properties but exists in outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this error because there was a dependency on a library folder specified in my **settings.gradle**.  That folder had a lot of faulty configurations apparently.  So as soon as I removed it from settings.gradle, the project compiled just fine.